# Sharepoint multiple connections to a web parts

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to create connected web parts in Sharepoint that have multiple connections to the provider.

For example, 
Web Part A and B are the provider, and Web Part C is the consumer.

A is the provider to consumer C, and B is also the provider to consumer C.

Thanks.

Rhys, 
I tried this and doesn't seem to work. The consumer web part only works with whatever the last provider it sets to.

```
[ConnectionConsumer("KeywordsConsumer", "KeywordsID", AllowsMultipleConnections=true)]
public void ProviderReceiver1(ICommunicationChannel p)
{
       provider = p;
}

[ConnectionConsumer("NewEmployeeConsumer", "ID", AllowsMultipleConnections=true)]
public void ProviderReceiver2(ICommunicationChannel p)
{
    provider = p;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your using the same variable (**provider**) to store both references - thus one will replace the other.

Use

```
private ICommunicationChannel _keywordsProvider;
private ICommunicationChannel _newEmployeeProvider;

[ConnectionConsumer("KeywordsConsumer", "KeywordsID", AllowsMultipleConnections=true)]
public void ProviderReceiver1(ICommunicationChannel p)
{
     _keywordsProvider = p;
}

[ConnectionConsumer("NewEmployeeConsumer", "ID", AllowsMultipleConnections=true)]
public void ProviderReceiver2(ICommunicationChannel p)
{
     _newEmployeeProvider = p;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks! One more question, does it even need AllowsMultipleConnections attribute in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the web part C allows for multiple receivers.

If you are writing the web parts yourself you can define two receivers for web part C and then configure web part A to send data to receiver 1 and similarly web part B to send data for receiver 2.

Comment: You're correct - for example the built in List View Web Part (LVWP) will accept as a consumer (Web Part C) multiple connections in 2010 - but in 2007 it will only accept a single connection