# Multiple WebpartProviders to one single WebpartConsumer

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, webpart-connection

According to the user Rhys in this post [Sharepoint multiple connections to a web parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250973/sharepoint-multiple-connections-to-a-web-parts/4251011#4251011) you need to configure your providers to point to a specific consumer method. How do i do said configuration to the providers?

Answer (score 0):

Web part connections are very loosely coupled. The provider part exposes a method, marked with the ConnectionProvider attribute, that indicates it can provide information defined by a specific interface. The consumer part exposes a method, marked with the ConnectionConsumer attribute, that indicates it can consume information defined by a specific interface. When the provider and consumer use the same interface, they can communicate with each other. The communication is managed by the WebPartManager, not the web parts themselves.

This walkthrough should fill in the details and help you get started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx